# i want to clear 0 behind the decimals

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem because I want to show only a digit that isn't 0 such as

9 / 2 = 4.5 not 4.500000

8 / 3 = 2.666667

20 / 8 = 1.25 not 1.250000

Is there any code that will help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
float f = 4.500000f;
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", f];
```